# jqgrid setting custom formatter to dynamic column collection

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqgrid. We are building a dashboard functionality with jquery. Different application just have to register respective application page and dashboard will render that page.To achieve this we are using jqgrid as one of the jquery plugin. Following is my code

```
 var ph = '#' + placeHolder;  
    var _prevSort;  
    $.ajax({  
        url: dataUrl,  
        dataType: "json",  
        async: true,  
        success: function(json) {  
            pager = $('#' + pager); 
            if (json.showPager === "false") {  
                pager = eval(json.showPager);  
            }  
            dataUrl += "&jqSession=true";  
            $(ph).jqGrid({  
                url: dataUrl,  
                datatype: "json",  
                sortclass: "grid_sort",  
                colNames: JSON.parse(json.colNames),  
                colModel: JSON.parse(json.colModel),                  
                forceFit: true,  
                rowNum: json.rowNum,  
                rowList: JSON.parse(json.rowList),  
                pager: pager,  
                sortname: json.sortName,  
                caption: json.caption,  
                viewrecords: true,  
                viewsortcols: true,  
                sortorder: json.sortOrder,  
                footerrow: summaryFooter,  
                userDataOnFooter: summaryFooter,  
                jsonReader: {  
                    root: "rows",  
                    row: "row",  
                    repeatitems: false,  
                    id: json.sortName  
                },  
                gridComplete: function() {  
                    if (showFooter) {  
                        $(ph).append("<tr class=\"ui-widget-content jqgrow\"><td   style=\"overflow:visible; text-align:left;width:100%;font-weight:bold;\" class=\"ui-jqgrid-  title\" colspan=\"" + json.colNum + "\">" + json.footerRow + "</td></tr>");
                    }  
                    if (json.additionalContent != null) {  
                        $("#" + xContID).html(json.additionalContent);  
                    }  
                    $("ui-icon-asc").append("IMG");  
                    var _rows = $(".jqgrow");  
                    if (json.rows.length > 0) {  
                        for (var i = 1; i < _rows.length; i += 1) {  
                            _rows[i].attributes["class"].value =   _rows[i].attributes["class"].value.replace(" ui-jqgrid-altrow", "");  
                            if (i % 2 == 1) {  
                                _rows[i].attributes["class"].value += " ui-jqgrid-altrow";  
                            }  
                        }  
                        var gMaxHeight = getGridMaxHeight();  
                        var gHeight = ($(ph + " tr").length + 1) * ($($(".jqgrow")  [0]).height());  
                        if (gHeight <= gMaxHeight) {  
                            $(ph).parent().height(gHeight);  
                        }  
                        else {  
                            $(ph).parent().height(gMaxHeight);  
                        }  
                    }  
                    else {  
                        $(ph).prepend("<tr class=\"ui-widget-content jqgrow\"><td   style=\"overflow:visible; text-align:center;width:100%;font-weight:bold;\" class=\"ui-  jqgrid-title\" colspan=\"" + json.colNum + "\">" + gridNoDataMsg + "</td></tr>");  
                        $(ph).parent().height(60);  
                    }  
                },  
                onSortCol: function(index, iCol, sortorder) {                      
                    dataUrl = dataUrl.replace("&jqSession=true", "");  
                    $(ph).jqGrid().setGridParam({ url: dataUrl }).trigger("reloadGrid");  
                    var _colName = "#jqgh_" + index;  
//                    $(_prevSort).parent().removeClass("ui-jqgrid-sorted");  
//                    $(_prevSort).parent().addClass("ui-state-default");  
//                    $(_colName).parent().addClass("ui-jqgrid-sorted");  
//                    $(_colName).parent().removeClass("ui-state-default");  
                    _prevSort = _colName;  
                    var _rows = $(".jqgrow");  
                    for (var i = 1; i < _rows.length; i += 1) {  
                        _rows[i].attributes["class"].value =   _rows[i].attributes["class"].value.replace(" ui-jqgrid-altrow", "");  
                        if (i % 2 == 1) {  
                            _rows[i].attributes["class"].value += " ui-jqgrid-altrow";  
                        }  
                    }  
                }  
            }).navGrid('#' + pager, { search: false, sort: false, edit: false, add: false,   del: false, refresh: false }); // end of grid  
            $("#" + loadid).empty();  
            gGridIds[gGridIds.length] = placeHolder;  
            SetGridSizes();  
        },  
        error: function() {  
            $("#" + loadid).html(loadingErr);  
        }  
    });
```

As you can see from the code i am getting column collection dynamically(Appication page which i am calling will give me JSON in the response and will have colNames collection in it. Evrything is working fine but, only issue is coming when we are trying to apply custom formatter to  column. This issue comes only when we are dynamically assign "colModel" to jqgrid.

Appreciate help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I find your approach very interesting. Mostly for the purpose will be used `jqGrid.jqGridExport` see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:import_methods. The only thing which I find a little strange, that you don't use `contentType: 'application/json'` as a `$.ajax` option. In this case the received data will be converted to an object by `$.ajax`. Next suspected thing is that you don't decode the JSON respond with respect of one `JSON.parse` call.

If this advise will not help you I'll suggest that you post a test JSON response contains custom formatter with which you have problems. Then I'll be able to reproduce your problem without having connection to your server.